# How to include scrollbar width when using fit-to-content modes?

Tags: css, scrollbar

In CSS there are several "modes" to express the intent that the given block/cell size should fit to its content. For example for grid cell it is "auto" or "min-content" (they don't mean the same, I know).

The problem with all those modes are (at least in Firefox) the content is calculated without scrollbar. So when I scroll the content the scrollbar overlaps a bit of the content.

Is there some switch/mode that would reserve the space needed for scrollbar? If this help I am struggling with vertical scrollbar.

*Unless I miss something padding is no-go because it would require knowing the size of the scrollbar.*

**Update**:

I am looking for something like:

```
... style="padding-right: calc(scrollbar-width)" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Im no pro myself, but for me it sounds like you could add a `margin-right:` to the `div` element, this will make the content move to the left side, which then gives more space on the right for the scrollbar

Comment: This does not differ from padding approach really -- I would need to know or compute the scrollbar width. So then the question changes how to do it.

Comment: Oh, so you mean this one: ```scrollbar-width: auto | thin | none | <length>;```

Comment: Not really, but thank you very much for pointing this out. I don't want to change the scrollbar, I want to reserve the room for it in advance.